# Basic auth only if a certain header is present in the request?

Tags: nginx

**Q**: I want to be able to enable basic authentication for only those requests, that include a specific header in the request.

**Use case:** Ask authentication for only certain clients whose requests are coming through LB(and match on the headers the LB sets).

I tried playing with the IF directive, but it didn't work out. Anynone have a small config example of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [`auth_basic`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic) directive, you can not use the directive in a `if` block but you can use variables as values.

So use a map to test for specific conditions and use the resulting variable.

```
map $http_<header_name> $authentication {
    default    "off";
    "~^"       "my_realm";
}


server {

     ...    

    location /foo {

        auth_basic $authentication;
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/htpasswd/file;

        ...
    }

}
```

The `<header_name>` pattern must be replaced with the name of the header using lowercase letters and underscore instead of dashes (e.g. `My-Header` becomes `$http_my_header`)