# Conditional basic auth and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have a SPA that must be accesible only from some countries, while it should require basic auth from other countries. I'm currently using CloudFlare's `cf_ipcountry` header in order to figure out from which country the request is coming from.

I know I can do conditional basic auth with NGNIX, as described here: [Basic auth only if a certain header is present in the request?](https://serverfault.com/questions/643711/basic-auth-only-if-a-certain-header-is-present-in-the-request)

On the other hand, if the user agent is `googlebot` or `bingbot`, I need to `proxy_pass` the request to another backend server that will render the SPA (evaluate the javascript) into HTML.

The end result should look something like this:

```
map $http_cf_ipcountry $authentication {
    default    "off";
    "US"       "basic_auth";
    "CA"       "basic_auth";
}

map $http_user_agent $ssr {
    default  0;

    "bingbot"    1;
    "googlebot"  1;
}

server {
    ...

    location / {
        auth_basic $authentication;
        auth_basic_user_file /......./basic_auth;

        include proxy_params;
        if ($ssr = 1) {
            proxy_pass http://backend_server;
        }

        if ($ssr = 0)
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

but `try_files` inside `if` is not allowed. How can I tweak my conf in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        if ($ssr) {
            set $authentication "off";
            proxy_pass http://backend_server;
            break;
        }

        auth_basic $authentication;
        auth_basic_user_file /.......x/basic_auth;

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```