# Nginx: http auth if a header is NOT present?

Tags: nginx

How can I make nginx ask for a basic auth if a certain header is NOT present?
I have found a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/643711/basic-auth-only-if-a-certain-header-is-present-in-the-request) where if the header is present, basic auth is shown.

How do I make the other way around?

Comment: Did you try just reversing it?

Comment: How? That's my question actually.

Comment: @needtoask `map $http_<header_name> $authentication { "~." "off"; default "my_realm"; }`

Comment: It doesn't work. I dont' understand why. What does "~." mean? (I am not an admin, just trying to figure things out here)